# Keep ipod classic settings on new pc

Tags: itunes, ipod, data-transfer, default-settings

I use iPod classic with the latest iTunes on a Windows XP pc.  Itl file and all music files are on a USB drive.

Now I have a new Windows 10 pc and I'd like to use it to manage iTunes.

I already set a fixed drive letter to the external drive (identical on both pcs) and of course I could open iTunes on the new pc and set the location of the library and everything would work until I connect the iPod classic.

The new iTunes would not recognise my iPod settings and treats it as a new device so I have to resync all from scratch.

Actually I already experienced this scenario twice in the past, with different pc changes, I haven't yet connected the iPod to the latest pc.

So before connecting it I ask for advice: do you know a trick to keep the settings? Maybe there is a sort of device Id to be transferred but I do not know where I can find it.

Regards.

Comment: Did you copy everything from `My Documents\My Music\iTunes` in Windows XP to `C:\Users\USERNAME\My Music\iTunes` in Windows 10 before you started iTunes?

Comment: Actually no, my itl file is on usb so I forgot that folder, but I will check if there are files to be copied there. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you want to keep the itl files on your USB stick, then you can always hold down SHIFT whilst you start iTunes. It'll then ask you to select the location of that folder. Source: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201596

Comment: I know the shift trick,  the only thing I always fail to transfer in iTunes are iPod settings, that's why I ask for advice before connecting it. I will check if there are still files on the user folder to be moved on the new pc.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, it works. Actually I already moved also .itl on usb so c:\... was not in use any more. I opened iTunes with shift, selected the library. It worked for a few minutes. When I got back control my music was there, including my complex smart playlist setup. I plugged in iPod and it kept all the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Richard was right, it worked by My Documents\My Music\iTunes My Documents\My Music\iTunes in the new pc.